# Update JSON.parsed object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am trying to update the parsed object.data is the JSON object received from the server.

```
var document_text = JSON.parse(data.projectData[0]['document_text']);
for(var j = 0; j < document_text.length;j++)
{
    var k = JSON.parse(document_text[j]);
    var document_data = JSON.parse(k).text;
    var page_number = JSON.parse(k).page_number;
}
```

Now i want to update the document_text object which contains the text and the page_number field.Note that i have to parse the object two times.First to parse the outer value then to get the inner value.How can i update the the fields of document_text(i.e text,page_number).

This is the original data

```
 ["\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Osddsdsdsdsds \\\\n\\\\n to  as \\\\\\\"sdfdsdsfsdfsdfsdf\\\\\\\") and CPGsddsdsdsdssdROsdsdsdsdP sdsdds,  a \\\\sd  sdds\\\\n\\\\n\\\\f\\\",\\\"page_number\\\":44}\"","\"{\\\"text\\\":\\\"Page  14 \\\\n\\\\nsdfsdfsdfdscopysdsdds\\\n\\\\n\\\\f\\\",\\\"page_number\\\":45}]
```

Comment: A small example input and expected output would really help here...

Comment: are you sure you need all those `JSON.parse()`? Normally you just need one to transform the serialized data into a materialized object and tag along with that. As you have written there are many levels of JSON nested in JSON nested in JSON... like triple nesting. This is legit but are you sure you have that?

Comment: Please provide an example of the original data, probably condensed so that we don't need to see the actual data (looks legal BTW; might not be a good idea to paste that data on a public website).

Comment: That can't be your original data. In your first line of code, you're accessing a `projectData` array property on your `data` variable. There's no `document_text` node in there at all. What you've posted is not even valid JavaScript. Please take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```
var document_text = JSON.parse(data.projectData[0]['document_text']);

/* At this point, document_text is already a JSON object. Iterating over it with 
a for loop doesn't make much sense. You can now just access its properties directly. */

document_text.text = "Some other text";
document_text.page_numer = 1;

/* Now we can return it to where it came from by stringify'ing it */

data.projectData[0]['document_text'] = JSON.stringify(document_text);
```

Comment: Actually document_text is an array thats why i am iterating over it

Comment: The text you posted before editing your post is just a single object. Regardless you only need to call JSON.parse once even if that is the case.